# Window Phone Emulator Error while Running Program Emulator start and show window logo and stop again

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

My window phone 8 emulator not able to start when I run program from vs2012 emulator start loading after some time emulator automatic shut down. when I see the progress of running emulator while running program in Hyper-v there showing window log and emulator stop and again start, this will happen many time and after some time emulator off and in Vs2012 showing Deployment fail.

But before I tried it works properly, when emulator run emulator that time internet is not available show I searched in Internet for solution I removed network switches and run Xdecleanup but problem is still persist.

My Machine Configuration:

Processor : Core-i7 2.20 GHz
RAM : 4gb
Graphics : 2gb
HDD : 1TB
Hypervisor : Present.

Software : Visual Studio 2012
SDK : Window Phone 8

Answer (score -1):

step 1:Goto Hyper-v manager 
step 2:Choose file menu and click on options. Options dialog opens in that click on delete files button. You are ready to go now.
This worked for me.